# looping through data in DAL

Tags: vb.net

In my dal it loops through each in my datatable then applies to my object class. What I want to be able to do is before it is passed into my object class is check if the row that was previously passed has the same product code. for example;

Current row of data is;

```
ProductCode quantity
100001         500
```

if the previous line of data passed has the same product code;

```
ProductCode quantity
100001         500
```

it will add the quantity with the previous line to make 1000.

if not the same productcode then just apply it to my object class as normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want [running total](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) in the `DataTable`? You could use LINQ:

```
var runningTotalsPerCode = table.AsEnumerable()
.Select(row => new
{
    ProductCode = row.Field<int>("ProductCode"),
    Quantity = row.Field<int>("Quantity"),
    AllFields = row.ItemArray
})
.GroupBy(x => x.ProductCode)   // group by the product-code
.SelectMany(g => g.            // flatten the group after the running-total was calculated
    Select((x, index) => new
    {
        x.ProductCode,
        x.Quantity,
        x.AllFields,
        RunningTotal = g.Take(index + 1).Sum(xx => xx.Quantity) 
    }));
```

Then you can loop it to create a new `DataTable` or pass the values to your object.

**Edit**: whoops, i only just noticed that you want VB.NET. Give me some minutes....

```
Dim codeGroups = From row In table
                 Let ProductCode = row.Field(Of Int32)("ProductCode")
                 Let Quantity = row.Field(Of Int32)("Quantity")
                 Let Code = New With {ProductCode, Quantity, .AllFields = row.ItemArray}
                 Group Code By Code.ProductCode Into CodeGroup = Group
Dim runningTotalsPerCode = codeGroups.
    SelectMany(Function(g) g.CodeGroup.Select(Function(x, index) New With
    {
        g.ProductCode,
        x.Quantity,
        x.AllFields,
        .RunningTotal = g.CodeGroup.Take(index + 1).Sum(Function(xx) xx.Quantity)
    }))
```

Quick test with this sample data:

```
Dim table As New DataTable()
table.Columns.Add("ProductCode", GetType(Int32))
table.Columns.Add("Quantity", GetType(Int32))
table.Rows.Add(555555, 777)  ' other group
table.Rows.Add(100001, 500)
table.Rows.Add(100001, 444)
table.Rows.Add(100001, 442)

ProductCode=555555, Quantity=777, AllFields={Length=2}, RunningTotal=777    <anonymous type>
ProductCode=100001, Quantity=500, AllFields={Length=2}, RunningTotal=500    <anonymous type>
ProductCode=100001, Quantity=444, AllFields={Length=2}, RunningTotal=944    <anonymous type>
ProductCode=100001, Quantity=442, AllFields={Length=2}, RunningTotal=1386   <anonymous type>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a reference to the previously created business object. If the previous object code equals the current code, then combine the information into the previous object.

Depending on the amount of data and how your business logic is done. This can be done after your loop. When all your business object are created and inserted in a list. You could add a function to the list that will combine similar product code.

A much better option would be to do all of this in the database and have the query return just what is needed.